# .Net Core InvokeCoreAsync has null result

Tags: signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

Using Postman WebSockets I get the expected response to this message sent to the hub:

```
{
  "type": 1,
  "target": "RequestAuthToken",
  "arguments": [
    "123456"
  ]
}
```

e.g. {"type":1,"target":"AuthResultReceived","arguments":["{"Token":"KWFRMHUkTVL74Gsxqf...

but when I use a .Net 6 client I get a null result.

```
_Hub = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("https://localhost:44379/api").Build();
await _Hub.StartAsync();

RequestAuthTokenResponse result = await _Hub.InvokeCoreAsync<RequestAuthTokenResponse>("RequestAuthToken", new string[] { "123456" });
```

Any thoughts on what I'm missing?  I've tried changing the type to "object" and "string" to try to get around any de-serialization issue.  The hub side seems happy in either case.

Comment: What version were you using before, it worked right then? What changes have you made since you are now using .net 6? You can check out this simple example:https://www.telerik.com/blogs/bring-your-apps-life-signalr-dotnet-6

Comment: This is new client code.  Other clients (and Postman) are working fine.

Comment: Facing a similar issue. If I put the JsonObject type in InvodeCoreAsync, at least it is giving the object but then I can't deserialize it.